# Strange behavior of generic type

Tags: c#, generics

Please look at simple code below

```
public class A{}

  public class B: A{}

  public class G<T> where T : A
  {
    public T GetT()
    {
      return new A();
    }
  }
```

This code is incorrect - compiler error "Cannot convert A to return type T". 
But A is actually T. If I change

```
return new A();
```

to

```
 return new A() as T;
```

everything is ok. What is the reason of that behavior? 
Thanks in advance

UPD: there was an error in initial question. Now fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Reworked answer based on update*

Although `A` meets the generic constraint `where T : A`, it's a concrete type. However, your generic class's `GetT()` method has a generic return type of `T`, so you have to cast your concrete type to your generic type to make the returns compatible.

The old answer holds true for your previous case of returning `new B()`.

---

*Old answer*

The generic type constraint says that `T` must inherit from `A`; however, it does *not* say that `T` must be `B` (or a derivation of it), although `B` happens to itself inherit from `A` and meet the constraint.

So the return type isn't compatible (`B` is always `B`, but `T` is not necessarily `B`), and you get the error.

Comment: ok, even if change return new B(); to return new A();, I got an error. return new A() as T; works fine

Comment: @Gopher: `A` is concrete, but `T` is generic. Since the return type is generic, what you're returning must be of the generic type.

Comment: that's the explanation. Thanks!

Comment: I find your answer a little confusing. I think that if you say that B is not necessarily a T, will make it clearer.

Answer (score 6):

Imagine what would happen if you did:

```
public class C : A{}

G<C> x = new G();
C c = x.GetT();
```

You really don't want that to return a `B` reference...

The `as` operator works because then it'll just return `null` if `T` isn't either `B` or `A`... but that's probably not *really* what you meant.

It's hard to know the course of action to suggest, without knowing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The same code, just with names changed

```
public class Animal{}

public class G<T> where T : Animal
{
     public T GetT()
     {
       return new Animal();
     }
}

Fish fish = new G<Fish>().GetT();
```

But GetT() doesn't return a Fish, it returns an anonymous "Animal". There's a problem : even if the contrary is true, all animals are not fish. You cannot return an Animal if a Fish is needed, and not any other kind of Animal.

Answer (score 0):

`where T : A` means T must inherit from A.  Therefore, `T` might not be an `A`, so you can't just return a `B`, as `C` might also be inherit from `A`, but a `B` isn't a `C`.